# Passing data from a POST request and broadcasting to a websocket in Micronaut

Tags: post, websocket, kotlin, javabeans, micronaut

Let's say I have a class called "`WebSocketAdapter`" annotated with `@ServerWebSocket`.  This class has `@OnOpen`,  `@OnClose`, `@OnMessage` functions similar to the chat example.

Inside my class I have a constructor that is passed in a `WebSocketBroadcaster`.  Inside my socket functions I have a `WebSocketSession` which I can save out to the object if I want, but I am actually using the broadcaster to broadcast to all open sockets.

Next, I have an `@Controller` class with a `@Post` controller function. This just writes the posted data with `println`.

This may or may not be relevant: I am using an `@Singleton` with `DefaultRouteBuilder` to `@Inject` the POST controller dynamically.

Finally, I have my `index.html` set up as a static resource with a simple script built to consume websockets append data to the DOM.

So, I can stand up micronaut, visit `localhost` and see data stream in from my socket to the page. Also, I can post to my endpoint and see data in the console.

My question is how can I make my socket session broadcast when I post to the post controller? How exactly do I inject the websocket as a depenedency of the post controller so I can send the message posted to the server to all open browsers? Note: I am using Kotlin but open to any suggestion in any language.

Things I have tried:

- Passing `WebSocketSession` directly into the post controller and hoping it
  gets 'beaned' in
- Trying to access the bean via
  `BeanContext.run().getBean(WebSocketAdapter::class.javaClass)` and use it's broadcaster or session
- Making the `@ServerWebSocket` a `@Singleton` and using `@Inject` on the
  session and trying to access it
- Trying to find bean using `@ApplicationContext` and use it's session
- Using rx to pass data between the classes (I am familiar with RxSwift)

I seem to be getting an error like: `Bean Context must support property resolution`

The documentation says

> The WebSocketSession is by default backed by an in-memory map. If you add the the session module you can however share sessions between the HTTP server and the WebSocket server.

I have added the session module to my .gradle however, how exactly do I share my sessions between `ws://` and `http://` with micronaut?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of SimpMessagingTemplate in Micronaut.
They way I got around this was to create an internal @WebSocketClient which allowed me to connect to server. The server recognises the connection as internal due to the way I authorise it and interprets messages on this socket as commands that are interpreted and executed.

It works, but SimpMessagingTemplate would be better.

Answer (score 0):

This technique worked for me:

```
def sockServer = Application.ctx.getBean(MySocketServer)
sockServer.notifyListeners("you've been notified!")
```

In my case this code resides in an afterInsert() method in a GORM object in a micronaut server. Calls would come in to a controller and update a GORM object, and the changes are sent out to listener.